# Java 2D game: repaint

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a very simple game for my homework and right now I am solving the following problem:

in this game when you `click` on the `shape` (for now it is just a circle) it should dissapear and render a new one somewhere else (you are collecting points when you hit that shapes, that´s the point) and my problem is in the `mouseClicked` method, i think. I put some control `System.out.println()` there and everytime when the program reach this method it displays as many prints as there was circles. I mean, if you click on the first circle it displays one print, if you click on the second circle it diplays two prints and so on. Can you help me pls? I just started with the `swing` and `awt` and I don´t have much time for thorough study. Thank you so much.

```
public class Shape extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    Graphics2D g2;
    Ellipse2D circle;
    Timer t = new Timer(2000, this);
    int x, y, count;
    JLabel counting;

    public Shape(JLabel counting){
        this.counting = counting;
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        ListenForMouse lForMouse = new ListenForMouse();

        addMouseListener(lForMouse);

        Random ran = new Random();

        int green = ran.nextInt(256);
        int red = ran.nextInt(256);
        int blue = ran.nextInt(256);

        Color randomColor = new Color(green, red, blue);

        int wid = ran.nextInt(101) + 50;

        x = ran.nextInt(650);
        if(x > wid)
            x = x - wid;
        y = ran.nextInt(600);
        if(y > wid)
            y = y - wid;

        circle =  new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,wid,wid);

        t.start();

        g2.setColor(randomColor);

        g2.fill(circle);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        repaint();

    }


    private class ListenForMouse implements MouseListener{

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


                System.out.println("Control before");

            if(circle.contains(e.getPoint())){

                count++;    

                counting.setText(Integer.toString(count));

                t.stop();

                repaint();

                System.out.println("Control in");
            }
            System.out.println("Control out");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has stated "I don´t have much time for thorough study" which indicates they have not done adequate research before asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because you add a new mouse listener every time `paintComponent` is called. You should do this once, inside the constructor.